# Retweeted text still includes RT and @ name

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to format retweets like twitter does it - Having the tweet include the retweeted user's profile pic, name and text.

To do this, I am pulling the user profile pic, name and tweet id out of the "retweeted_status", such as...

```
$rt_profile_img = $result->retweeted_status->user->profile_image_url;
$rt_screen_name = $result->retweeted_status->user->screen_name;
$rt_text = $result->retweeted_status->text;
```

The profile image and screen name work, but for some reason, the text output is still like this-

```
RT @user: message
```

I want to loose the "RT @user" and just keep the message. Thats what the "text" field under "retweeted_status" provides, but it's not displaying it like that. I am displaying the right $rt_text too in my output. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use str_replace()?

Comment: Ideally not. The text field under "retweeted_status" excludes the format I want to get rid of. What I can't figure out is why it's still not returning that way.

Comment: However, I tried this idea, and it works fine, so I don't see why I shouldn't use it. Thanks!